# Hibernate Mapping for Oracle RAW column

Tags: oracle, hibernate

We're using Hibernate and not sure how to map properties to RAW columns in Oracle table (specifically that have indexes on them).

It's a known fact that **String** can't be used for entity property value - Hibernate isn't able to prepend the **HEXTORAW** Oracle function call in order to make index on a column to be used (cause without this Oracle implicitly appends RAWTOHEX to column value itself).

However, it's not clear whether using **byte[]** as an entity property value is solving this issue or not. Since JDBC driver is sending binary data directly - it's logical to assume that index would be used - cause there is no any need to execute neither **HEXTORAW** nor **RAWTOHEX** functions.

However, I'm not sure how to prove it (except putting million of records and performing some benchmarks). 
I tried to search similar questions but without success.

Does anyone has knowledge about that?
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3):

Final answer - yes, mapping byte[] works.

Tested that on a table with millions of records and primary key of RAW type.

It took ~2 minutes to lookup a record by PK if using String.

With byte[] record was found immediately.